# Why isn't font-family working on all pages on my Website?

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-family, elementor

I have changed the font-family on my Website's frontpage, but have been unable to synchronize that across all of the other pages of my site. I have compared the inspect coding in Chrome between the frontpage and the Shop, for example, and see no differences there. Can anyone help me solve this one?

https://youmeitea.com <-- this page is working as intended, the font in question is in the upper left corner in the header

https://youmeitea.com/shop <-- this page is not working as intended, the font in the upper left corner is not in the Berkshire Swash font

Thanks for any help or suggestions, I am happy to experiment to get it working right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have compared the inspect coding in Chrome between the frontpage and the Shop, for example, and see no differences there

That's because the `font-family` CSS rule is indeed there. However, the font is not being displayed because you're only embedding it on the front page.

That is, the following is only present on the front page:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" id="google-fonts-1-css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Berkshire+Swash%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic%7CSource+Serif+Pro%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic&amp;ver=5.4" type="text/css" media="all">
```

You have to fix the way you're enqueueing the Berkshire Swash to apply to *all* pages.

Alternatively, try embedding the font via [@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) in your stylesheet:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Berkshire+Swash%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic%7CSource+Serif+Pro%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic&amp;ver=5.4');
```

---

**Edit:** You can enqueue Berkshire Swash (or any other font, for that matter) from a child theme by hooking into [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/), like that:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sean_enqueue_google_fonts' );

function sean_enqueue_google_fonts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Berkshire+Swash%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic%7CSource+Serif+Pro%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic&amp;ver=5.4', array() );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I will investigate this further. Do you happen to know of a good way to apply this to our pages via a child theme?

Comment: Thanks for your edit and expertise my friend, I will try it out!

Comment: Happy to help! Let me know if you need any clarification :)